# set mongodb node.js connection once for all routes using mongoclient

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new in node.js and mongo db and i have done my code like this in all my routes.

```
var express       = require('express');
var router        = express.Router();
var mongo         = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient   = mongo.MongoClient;
var ObjectID      = mongo.ObjectID;
var collection;

//Connection to mongo db using mongo client
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb', function(err, db) {

    //connection error or success message
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log("connected to the mongoDB");
    }

    //index
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        collection = db.collection('category');
        collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, category) {
            collection = db.collection('subcategory');
            collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, subcategory) {
                collection = db.collection('product');
                collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, product) {
                    collection = db.collection('banner');
                    collection.find({status: 'A'}).toArray(function(err, banner) {
                        console.log(banner);
                        res.render('home', 
                            {
                                title           : 'Home', 
                                categorys       : category,
                                subcategorys    : subcategory,
                                products        : product,
                                banner          : banner 
                            }
                        );
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

please help me to make a connection in common and access it from all my routes without repeating the connection call. thanks in advance

Comment: Can you use the [edit] link on your question to include your document schema perhaps with an example, and what it is you are expecting to get from the sample? If you could do that it would help clarify your problem because from inspection it looks like you might be vacationing in [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the draft code to keep the connection outside each request (i.e. connect once) and reuses the database/collection variable.

NodeJS Mongo Driver default connection pool size is 5.

Important: db and categoryCollection  variables are kept outside each requests.

```
var express = require('express');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var app = express();
var MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb';
var db;
var categoryCollection;
// Initialize connection once
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, function(err, database) {
  if(err) throw err;

  db = database;
  categoryCollection = db.collection('category');
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
app.get('/', function(req, res) { 
 categoryCollection.find({}).toArray(function(err, category) {  
 });                        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/) to connect to MongoDB. With Mongoose you need to connect to the database only once to access it  from all the routes. In you `app.js` add these lines:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test_db', { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

and in your routes you can now access MongoDB without having to write any connection code.